# Simple ODE question...

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've run up on something that is intuitively obvious but I am having a little trouble seeing formally. Could someone show me exactly why $y^\prime=-2+t-y$ is asymptotic to $y=x-3$. Thanks, in advance for any assistance that you might be able to lend.

Comment: thx kris, appreciate it.

Comment: Did you try to solve the DFQ?

Comment: Yes, C/e + (t-3).

Comment: @court I think you have a typo. You should have $y= \frac{C}{e^{-t}} + (t-3)$. Then we can take the limit as $t$ approaches infinity  on the exponential part and see what the solution looks like.

Comment: Yes, yes. You are correct. But, as he said, it becomes clear that as it goes off to infinity the e term goes away and thus the described behavior. Thanks a million guys!!

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that $y'=-2+t-y$ should be $y'=-2+x-y$. Letting $u=y-x+3$, then the DE becomes
$$ u'=-u. $$
Hence $u=Ce^{-x}$. So $\lim_{x\to\infty}u=0$ and hence the solution of $y'=-2+x-y$ is asymptotical to $y=x-3$.

Comment: Thanks. I really appreciate it. I'll have to think about it. Thanks again.

Comment: The interchange of x and t is well observed. It's good that you solved it, Court, because taking the limit to infinity on the e-power makes it "disappear. And what do we get????

Comment: I would vote it up but, as yet, I don't have the rep to vote anything up. Thanks again.

Comment: As long as you understand it now :)